# Laravel: Multiple Polymorphic relationships in a Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a Table Named Comments with following structure

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->morphs('commentable');
$table->morphs('creatable');
$table->text('comment');
$table->timestamps();
});
```

Eloquent File

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['comment'];

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function creatable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

where I have two polymorphic relationships

`commentable` for any Article/Post or a Video

`creatable` for the comment Creator of the comment User/Admin

How to add comment against a Post created by a user?

I tried creating using following code

```
public function addComment($creatable, $comment)
{
        $this->comments()->create(['comment' => $comment, 'creatable' => $creatable]);
}
```

It did work, I received following Error

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'creatable_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `post_comments` (`comment`, `commentable_id`, `commentable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Test Comment, 1, App/Post, 2018-08-31 10:29:14, 2018-08-31 10:29:14))'
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: add error and relations in your model

Comment: Information Added @J.Doe

Comment: Your `Comment` model should have only one method. Also, `comments` table should have different structure including `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` if you want to use default polymorphic relations. Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) again. If I am not wrong, your `comments` table has more fields than needed.

Comment: My implementation is different than what's given in the Documentation, in the documentation they are dealing with only one Polymorphic relation, In my case I need multiple. `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` will be added to the table auto. because of `$table->morphs('commentable');` @Tpojka

Comment: Not easy to say without seeing table diagram, but maybe you need `$table->nullableMorphs('commentable');` and `$table->nullableMorphs('creatable');` in table (allowed null values)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `make()`:

```php
public function addComment($creatable, $comment)
{
        $this->comments()->make(['comment' => $comment])
            ->creatable()->associate($creatable)
            ->save();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, it didn't work, I even tried `enableQueryLog()` at the start of the function and `getQueryLog()` in the end, it returned `[]`

Comment: How are you calling `addComment()`?

Comment: `$post->addComment($user, "This is my comment");` where `$post` is a `commentable` and `$user` is a `creatable`

Comment: Is `$user` coming from the database (`User::find()`) or freshly created (`new User()`)?

Comment: Coming from database using `find` method `$user = User::find(1);`

Comment: What's the result of `dd($this->comments()->make(['comment' => $comment])->creatable()->associate($creatable));`?

Comment: This answer worked, there was a mistake which I made, I was trying `associates` instead of `associate`, thank you for your answer and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I need model instead of bool in return?